# Does image_dataset_from_directory load all the images into memory at once?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm new to machine learning, and I am trying to create an image classifier, I want to load the dataset, but I want to do it in a way such that it does not take up all of my memory. Reading the tensorflow documentation, it says that iteration of a dataset happens in streaming fashion, and I am wondering if tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory will load the images at once or "stream" it a batch at a time. If not I was thinking of making a generator to read file names one at a time and load them when the batches are ready with keras.utils.Sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory, labels='inferred', label_mode='int', class_names=None,
    color_mode='rgb', batch_size=32, image_size=(256, 256), shuffle=True, seed=None,
    validation_split=None, subset=None, interpolation='bilinear', follow_links=False
)
```

If you define batch size it will generate data `according to batch size` otherwise `default batch size is 32`. **It is never possible to load the whole data in a single batch in normal computer.** For more details read [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory).

Comment: So it loads only the batch at a time from directory?

Comment: so what if we want to train data of more than 1000 records, how we gonna load 1000 images at a time..

Answer (score 0):

Use `dataset.unbatch()` to revert the dataset in to a single batch.

```
dataset = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  image_size=(256, 256),
  batch_size=batch_size,
  shuffle=False)

dataset = dataset.unbatch()
```